# Trying to understand pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble trying to grasp a couple of things inside the py game code, firstly why are there two types of quit or are these the same? for example:

```
pygame.QUIT 
pygame.quit()
```

Also I can't grasp this small piece code fully:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

I understand the first line of code, but I don't understand event.type?, is `.type` a function inside of pygame or python in general? what does it do?

Comment: Your misunderstanding has more to do with python than pygame...functions calls will (generally) end with a `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is simply a constant, while `pygame.quit()` is a function within the `pygame` module that uninitializes it. The fragment of code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        ...
```

is part of the typical control loop of a `pygame` program. The method `pygame.event.get()` returns the next event. If the type of event (an attribute of the event object) is `pygame.QUIT` then the application should do what is necessary to exit, including possibly calling `pygame.quit()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 pygame.QUIT
```

Is an enumeration for an input that signals for the program to quit

```
pygame.quit()
```

Is a function call to unload pygame modules. According to the docs it won't actually quit the game:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit
You could use sys.exit(0) for that.

This loop here:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Checks each event, if one of them has the value pygame.QUIT then some exit code should follow.

Comment: pygame.quit() doesn't exit the game, only unload pygame modules

Answer (score -1):

The manual for [pygame.quit()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) says:

> Uninitialize all pygame modules that have previously been initialized. When the Python interpreter shuts down, this method is called regardless, so your program should not need it, except when it wants to terminate its pygame resources and continue.

So you should normally call this method yourself.

pygame.QUIT is a so called event type. Pygame uses events to tell you something happened. The code checks each events in the queue and checks if a QUIT event happened.

`event.type` is something from pygame, and it tells you what type of event it is. By comparing it to `pygame.QUIT`, you can check if the `quit()` method has been called, and take steps to shutdown the game.

Comment: What `quit()` method are you talking about? `QUIT` event is pushed onto the queue when a user closes the window.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski pygame.quit(), like I linked to.

Comment: The quit event type has nothing to do with the quit function being called.